# How to avoid compatibility issues between Java EE and Jakarta EE?

Tags: java, compatibility, jakarta-migration

After Oracle donated Java EE to the Eclipse Foundation, it [was renamed to Jakarta EE](https://blogs.eclipse.org/post/wayne-beaton/renaming-java-ee-specifications-jakarta-ee).

With that, the `javax` namespace was changed to `jakarta`.

What does one need to take care about in order to avoid compatibility issues due to the change from Java EE to Jakarta EE?

Comment: [This is a canonical](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427206/10871900)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Don't mix Java EE and Jakarta EE dependencies

You cannot use Java EE and Jakarta EE together. You have to use one or the other.
If a project is using Java EE, there should not be any Jakarta EE dependencies in the project.

Here are a few examples of Java EE/Jakarta dependencies (in `group.id:artifact-id` notation):

| Java EE dependency | Jakarta EE dependency |
| --- | --- |
| `javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api` | `jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api` |
| `javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api` | `jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api` |
| `javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api` | `jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api` |
| `javax.validation:validation-api` | `jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api` |
| `javax.mail:javax.mail-api` | `jakarta.mail:jakarta.mail-api` |

You should not have both `javax` and `jakarta` dependencies in the same project.

You can use `mvn dependency:list` (with Maven) or `gradlew dependencies` (with Gradle) for checking your dependencies.

#### Other/transitive dependencies

Your project might use dependencies that are written for Java EE or Jakarta EE.
You need to make sure that you are using a version of these dependencies that matches the specification you are using.

This table provides examples of dependencies that use Java EE in some versions and Jakarta EE in other versions:

| Dependency | versions supporting Java EE | versions supporting Jakarta EE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Spring Boot | <= 2.x | >= 3.x |
| Spring | <= 5.x | >= 6.x |
| Hibernate | <= 5.x | >= 6.x |

### The package name

With the change of the name `Java EE` to `Jakarta EE`, all Java EE types were moved from the `javax` package to `jakarta` (e.g. `javax.servlet` was changed to `jakarta.servlet`).

If the project is using Java EE, it should not contain any `jakarta.*` imports and if it is using Jakarta EE, it should not use any Java EE classes from `javax.*`.

There are tools for changing all imports and other type references in a project.

#### configuration files

Some configuration files (e.g. `persistence.xml`) might be different depending on whether Java EE or Jakarta is used.

If configuration file references something starting with `javax`, this typically belongs to Java EE while references starting with `jakarta` typically belong in Jakarta EE projects.

Here is an example `persistence.xml` file for both Java EE and Jakarta EE:

```xml
<!-- This is for Java EE -->
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">

    <persistence-unit name="MyPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:my-database-url" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

```xml
<!-- This is for Jakarta EE -->
<persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd"
             version="3.0">
    <persistence-unit name="MyPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <properties>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:my-database-url" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Other configuration files might require similar changes.

### Application servers/Containers

Java EE projects should be deployed to an application server/web container supporting Java EE and Jakarta EE projects should be deployed to an application server/web container supporting Jakarta EE.

For example:

- [Tomcat <=9 uses Java EE while Tomcat >=10 uses Jakarta EE](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html)
- [Jetty 9 & 10 uses Java EE while Jetty 11 uses Jakarta EE](https://eclipse.dev/jetty/) — and [Jetty 12 supports both](https://webtide.com/introducing-jetty-12/) Java EE *and* Jakarta EE.

### Possible issues caused by incompatibilities

If a project references classes that are not available, `ClassNotFoundException`s/`NoClassDefFoundError`s can occur.

It is possible that some elements like servlets are not found by the container due to e.g. the container scanning for `javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet` but the servlet being annotated with `jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet`.

The application might not correctly pick up some configurations.

Of course, there can be many other issues depending on what exactly is done wrong.

### Migration tooling

There are tools that help migrate from Java EE to Jakarta EE.

For example, [Eclipse Transformer](https://github.com/eclipse/transformer) can do most of the migration steps and can perform the namespace change in both source code and existing JAR/WAR files (e.g. libraries). It is also available as a Maven plugin.

Alternatively, IntelliJ Ultimate allows [migrating the source code of existing projects from Java EE to Jakarta EE](https://www.jetbrains.com/guide/java/tutorials/migrating-javax-jakarta/use-migration-tool/). Similarly, [Spring Tools](https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/) allows to do the same for Spring projects.